# Download generated PDF use FileSaver on client side and Snappy on server side

Tags: angularjs, laravel, pdf, filesaver.js

I try to use FileSaver to download generated PDF from server. However, it's not work.

In Laravel framework, I use Snappy to create PDF file from HTML.

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('pub.view', $data);
//$pdf->save('myfile.pdf');    //It's saved successfully.
return $pdf->download('printing.pdf');
```

From client, I apply $resource service of AngularJS for getting PDF file.

```
printPDF: {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/pdf'
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            cache: true,
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                var pdf;
                if (data) {
                    pdf = new Blob([data], {
                        type: 'application/pdf'
                    });
                }
                return {
                    response: pdf
                };
            },
            url:'/u/:id/exportTopdf',
            params:{id:'@id'}
        }
```

After server response, FileSaver will save this file.

```
myService.printPDF({id: myId},
function successCallback(response){    

   saveAs(response, 'filename.pdf');  //FileSaver function

}, function errorCallback(response){

});
```

When running, the issue is happen in browser console:

```
`TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided`.
```

I think FileSaver makes the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I fixed it. My issues is response is not blob file. Response is object. I have to extract blob data in response and put in saveAs function. I download it by browser's downloader. However, FDM (free download manager) catch it after browser download. How can I make FDM catch it before browser?

Comment: FDM (free download manager) can not download blob file.

Answer (score 1):

```
param = {
  action: "downloadReport",
};
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/ivftcwcm2/services/fundTransferServices/downloadFile',
  //url:'http://localhost:8080/FundTransferUI/resources/locales/Disclosure.pdf',
  data: param,
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then(function(response) {
  var file = new Blob([response.data], {
    type: 'application/pdf'
  });
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = fileURL;
  a.target = '_blank';
  a.download = 'pdfFile.pdf';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
}, function(response) {
  alert('call failed');
});
```